# How to access to fields of a record type in postgresql without knowing their names?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm programming a PL/pgSQL function with this:

```
cols_to_select := according to a set of rules, we get the name of the columns

FOR I IN EXECUTE 'SELECT '||cols_to_select||' FROM tabl' LOOP
  -- how to access to fields of record I without knowing their names?
  -- 

END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way I figured out:

```
cols_to_select := according to a set of rules, we get the name of the columns

FOR I IN EXECUTE 'SELECT ARRAY['||cols_to_select||'] as AR FROM tabl' LOOP
  -- how to access to fields of record I without knowing their names?
  FOR j IN 1..array_upper(I.ar,1) LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '%', I.AR[j];
  END LOOP;

END LOOP;
```

The problem with this solution is that fails when the columns have different types.